# I need help understanding why I am getting an error in my LUA script

Tags: lua, fivem

This is my code:

```
RegisterServerEvent('aim_exchange:sellDrugs')
AddEventHandler('aim_exchange:sellDrugs', function()
    local src = source
    local player = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(src)
    SellDrugs(player)
end)

function SellDrugs(player)
    local drugs = {
        {
            name = "coke_small_brick",
            price = math.random(1, 50),
            amount = math.random(1, 3),
        },
    }

    local drug = nil
    for _, drugData in ipairs(drugs) do
        local itemName = drugData.name
        local itemPrice = drugData.price

        local foundItem = Player.Functions.GetItemByName(itemName)
        if foundItem and foundItem.amount >= drugData.amount then
            drug = { name = itemName, price = itemPrice, amount = drugData.amount }
            break
        end
    end

    if drug then
        Player.Functions.RemoveItem(drug.name, drug.amount)
        Player.Functions.AddItem("dirtymoney", drug.price)
        QBCore.Functions.Notify('Drug sold successfully.', success, 10000)
    else
        QBCore.Functions.Notify('You do not have enough drugs to sell.', success, 10000)
    end

    if math.random(1, 100) <= policeChance then
        CallPolice()
    end
end
```

This is the error I am getting:
SCRIPT ERROR: Execution of native 000000002f7a49e6 in script host failed: Argument at index 1 was null.

I'm not sure what that means, if anyone can help, but I will give any other details.

This is for a script I am writing for FiveM.  What I am trying to do is have it look through the players inventory until it finds one of the items listed in the "drugs" array.  Then it will remove the amount of drugs and give back "dirtymoney".

Basically the rest of the script that is working will spawn a ped/npc that will walk up to the player and prompt him to press "E" on his keyboard.   Once that happens, it should trigger the SellDrugs function listed above.

All of that is working, but once the function is triggered it is giving the error listed above.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely something to do with your EventHandler on line 2. I would take a look at the data you are using in that function to ensure they are what you would expect to be passed to the EventHandler. The error is saying that a script attempted to ["TriggerClientEventInternal" (a native function)](https://docs.fivem.net/natives/?_0x2F7A49E6) and the argument at index 1 was null.